# Avoid Facebook API session_start

Tags: facebook, zend-framework

I'm getting "session has already been started by session.auto-start or session_start()" error in my Zend Framework Application when I try to instantiate Zend_Session_Namespace. I assume it's facebook api's problem which tries to start the session by its own, I haven't used session_start() anywhere in my application. Is there any way to avoid this from happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe not the best solution but I solved it by editing in the Facebook class constructor the session_start() method and replaced it with Zend_Session::start();

Comment: I think that this is a fine solution. If the Facebook API were rewritten for Zend use it would probably include this sort of fix in it.

Answer (score 0):

Check your PHP ini file for this type of code
session.auto_start = true

If it's true then set it to false.

When you instantiate a Zend_Session_Namespace it will call session_start. The cool thing is that if you instantiate multiple namespaces only the first one will call session start.

If the session is started manually by you then you might get this error.

Another thing you could try is this

```
Zend_Session::setOptions( array( 'strict' = 'off' ) );
```

This will disable any namespace objects from automatically starting the session, allowing you to choose when to manually start the session yourself.